# Why should tests of an Angular application use the --no-sandbox option of Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, karma-runner

The information about [testing Angular](https://angular.io/guide/testing) includes an example configuration (of Karma and Protractor) in which it disables the sandbox of the Chrome browser:

```
browsers: ['Chrome'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCI: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
```

and

```
const config = require('./protractor.conf').config;

config.capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox']
  }
};

exports.config = config;
```

But **why**? Why not leave the sandbox enabled? Is there a good reason to do that? Is it necessary for tests to run properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons if you are using container for testing.

> Sandboxing  For security reasons, Google Chrome is unable to provide
> sandboxing when it is running in the container-based environment. To
> use Chrome in the container-based environment, pass the --no-sandbox
> flag to the chrome executable

[google-chrome Failed to move to new namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087200/google-chrome-failed-to-move-to-new-namespace)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the example code disables the sandbox, but for what it's worth, we leave it on in our test suite and everything is fine.  We used to specify `--no-sandbox` just like the examples, but removed it as a workaround to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4690), which was leaving orphaned chrome processes running after the test had completed.