# google-chrome Failed to move to new namespace

Tags: linux, docker, google-chrome, kubernetes-helm, google-chrome-headless

Im trying to run google-chrome --headless inside a docker container as a non-root user to execute some tests.
Everytime Im trying to start it, it throws following error:

**google-chrome --headless**

*Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Failed to generate minidump.Illegal instruction*

Its a docker container running in k8s cluster.
Operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Namespaces are enabled, user is non-root

I do not want to use --no-sandbox option as this is a security issue.

I cannot use docker run --security-opt=syscomp:unconfined as its being deployed using helm.

Is there a system permission missing that I need to setup for chrome within the container itself?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

After researching extensively internet I think I found the answer:

**Sandboxing** 
*For security reasons, Google Chrome is unable to provide sandboxing when it is running in the container-based environment.
To use Chrome in the container-based environment, pass the --no-sandbox flag to the chrome executable*

So it looks like there is no better solution than --no-sandbox for me, even though its not being very secure, there are people on the internet claiming that it is still safe to use "--no-sandbox" as its running within container which is extra protected any way.

Comment: If you needed i found a way, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345581/node-js-puppeteer-on-docker-no-usable-sandbox

Comment: even in vendor dir  typed by developer:  `sandbox mode - useful if you want to use chrome headless inside docker`  so add "noSandbox" and use docker

Answer (score 13):

Although this doesn't answer your question, since it you can't set `security-opt`, this is still a good solution for other people with a similar problem finding the question.

Download this [chrome.json](https://github.com/jessfraz/dotfiles/blob/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json) file, which contains a custom security profile.

Use the security profile with `--security-opt seccomp=path/to/chrome.json` or with docker-compose:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  <service name>:
    #
    # the service configuration
    #
    security_opt:
      - seccomp=<path to downloaded chrome.json>
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975412/8678740

---

## Update

This can now be done with `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` or in `docker-compose.yml` with:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  <service name>:
    #
    # the service configuration
    #
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
```

see: https://pptr.dev/guides/docker#usage