# Puppeteer chrome in docker: RUN fails but CMD works, why?

Tags: docker, google-chrome, puppeteer

I have been searching for an answer to this setup:

- I build a docker image with puppeteer and chrome ([docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md))
- In a separate stage I want to run unit tests prior to releasing the image
- When I use `RUN` to run puppeteer unit test, it fails
- When I use `CMD` to run puppeteer on container start, it works.

## When I do a RUN

I will get this result (which I really googled a lot)

```
0.629   1) chrome
0.629        should start
0.629          load some page, then exit:
0.629      Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
0.629 [18:18:1129/161517.426236:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(127)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
0.629 [1129/161517.432286:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
0.629 [1129/161517.432534:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
0.629
0.629
0.629 TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting
0.629
0.629       at Interface.onClose (node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:271:24)
0.629       at Interface.emit (node:events:529:35)
0.629       at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:534:10)
0.629       at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:260:10)
0.629       at Socket.emit (node:events:529:35)
0.629       at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)
0.629       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

## When I do a CMD

The `docker run`  command results in

```
  chrome
    should start
      ✔ load some page, then exit (568ms)


  1 passing (573ms)
```

## What I've tried

Even though I do not want to use `--no-sandbox` it did not work.

I do not understand, why the RUN command behaves differently.
The `No usable sandbox! Update your kernel` message resulted in the docker bit, where I allow
unpriveleged user creating namespaces:

```
RUN echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf
RUN service procps restart
```

I checked namspaces via

```
$ ls /proc/self/ns
cgroup  ipc  mnt  net  pid  pid_for_children  user  uts
```

and user is there. I did this also during docker build, and `user` was still there, but I may misunderstand the whole unprivileged user creating namespace thing.

I also tried `--disable-setuid-sandbox` without any luck

## Files for details

For sake of completeness this is the docker file (mostly taken from puppeteers docks for containers)

```
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as builder

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/chromeservice

COPY package*.json .
COPY .puppeteerrc.cjs .

RUN npm install

ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

RUN echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf
RUN service procps restart

RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser
RUN chown -R pptruser:pptruser .
RUN mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads
RUN chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser
USER pptruser

COPY --chown=pptruser:pptruser test.js .

FROM builder as test-stage

# Run tests, then get next version, and install only production
ENV NODE_PATH=.

# This fails
#RUN dumb-init -- node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha

CMD dumb-init -- node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

The test file

```
var assert = require('assert');
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

describe('chrome', function () {
  describe('should start', function () {
    it('load some page, then exit', async function () {
      
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch(
            { 
                headless: 'new',
                ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--hide-scrollbars']
            });

        await browser.close();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: When you have it as the `CMD`, how are you launching the container?  The image-build environment is somewhat restrictive; the things you're trying to do to for example change sysctls won't have an effect.  I wonder if this test might be better run in a local development environment, before you run any Docker commands at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze `docker run <sha of the build>`. Nothing fancy. I also removed the multi stage part for testing. No effect. The chrome thing is quite brittle, I ran all tests on my dev already, but I would like to have confidence, that the chrome-in-docker is also working up to specs. I also want to have a clean prod image without dev deps or test files in there, so I hoped to make this work.

Comment: @DavidMaze do you have a source, why sysctls won't work during build?

Comment: No specific documentation, but each `RUN` command is in a separate container, and when Docker runs a container it just runs the named process and nothing else.  So nothing reads `/etc/sysctl.d` at all, and anything `service procps restart` changes will be lost as soon as the temporary container exits.

Comment: @DavidMaze that would explain the behaviour but I think it might be incorrect. The dockerfile run docs does not say anything like that, also `RUN dumb-init -- cat /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf && service --status-all &&node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha` says that the `sysctl` entry was created, but procps is not running. When I run the exact same output in CMD, procps is still not running, but the chrome service is working fine.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: @Bravi Nope. I ended up removing all the unprivileged code thing, it was not needed and create a separate multistage called test,. where I execute the tests during start of the test-container. Unfortunately I cannot solve this from inside the dockerfile and have to resort to build scripts, that run the test container and if it passed, create the production layer and tag it

Comment: @Samuel so I've been struggling with the exact same thing. I tried puppeteer + nodejs, selenium + python but I always end up with the same sort of issue. So I ended up using `--no-sandbox` after trying tons of things and then just going for the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087200/google-chrome-failed-to-move-to-new-namespace

Comment: @Bravi I dig into the docs, for me no sandbox is not an option because I do not control some of the sites I am visiting. The container is critical not to endanger my host and I was able to make it run via CMD as a separate stage. If security is a concern, would this be viable for you?

Comment: Perhaps. Would you mind sharing your Dockerfile, or at least some parts of it?

Comment: @Bravi not at all, I'll prepare it and will post it tomorrow as an answer an mention you

Comment: @Bravi added my docker file as answer. Hope it helps

Comment: @Samuel much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This solution only works on windows docker containers with WSL because docker-desktop for windows actually is less secure, which is a very bad thing.

Read more, over at [my post at information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/273752/is-a-docker-container-that-requires-clone-and-unshare-syscalls-of-any-use).
The gist: docker on windows seems to use a less secure seccomp profile, that allows `clone` and `unshare` syscalls with out the `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` flag when doing a `docker run`. Using the default seccomp file from docker will also cause the container to fail on WSL as well. So currently I do not have a secure-enough proposal to run puppeteer and chrome in docker :/

---

So as I mentioned in the comments, I did not find a way to run tests in `RUN` but resolved it to create a separate image, that extends the production image. I've chosen this approach because I reckon that extending prod with test gives me more confidence about the prod image. Otherwise I would be building a test image and run tests and build a separate prod image to run production, without actually being sure, that the tests did mostly test my production image.

I also decided to go with debian-slim. Slim to reduce attack surface and image size. Alpine would be better, but while there is working Alpine image for chromium and puppeteer, I was very happy making it work on debian-slim.

My docker file builds three stages:

- builder -> builds the scripts
- produciton -> builds the prodcution image
- test -> extends production by test packages and test code

*Disclaimer: I mostly don't know, what I am doing because I lack experience with running hardened containers in production. If there is something I can improve, let me know*

I've tried to design the images in a way, that minimizes layer rebuilding due to cache invalidation of an too early COPY command (that's why it is fragmented in that way). Also created a `.dockerignore` for `node_modules and dist` just in case :D

(Also: I know I could use `--init` to use `tini` instead of `dumb-init` but I like to have my dependencies inside the docker file and not rely on correct calling of the container)

```
################ Builder phase ################

FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as builder

  ARG WORKDIR=/usr/chromeservice

  WORKDIR $WORKDIR

  COPY package*.json .
  COPY .puppeteerrc.cjs .

  # Install dependencies
  RUN npm install

  COPY config ./config
  COPY src ./src
  COPY test ./test
  COPY tsconfig.json .

  RUN npm run build

  CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]


################ Production phase ################
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as production

  ARG WORKDIR=/usr/chromeservice
  WORKDIR $WORKDIR

  RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
      && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
      && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
      && apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
        --no-install-recommends \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

  ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
  RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

  # Add non root user
  RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
      && mkdir -p $WORKDIR \
      && mkdir -p $WORKDIR\dist\src \
      && chown -R pptruser:pptruser $WORKDIR \
      && mkdir /home/pptruser \
      && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser

  USER pptruser
  
  COPY --from=builder --chown=pptruser:pptruser $WORKDIR/package*.json .
  COPY --from=builder --chown=pptruser:pptruser $WORKDIR/.puppeteerrc.cjs .

  # Install dependencies
  RUN npm install --omit=dev

  COPY --from=builder --chown=pptruser:pptruser $WORKDIR/config ./config
  COPY --from=builder --chown=pptruser:pptruser $WORKDIR/dist/src ./dist/src

  ENV NODE_ENV=production

  ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

  ENV NODE_PATH="$WORKDIR/dist"

  EXPOSE <A service port, if needed>

  CMD ["node", "dist/src/index.js"]


################ Test stage phase ################
FROM production as test
  
  # My Tests required a test http server, ommit if not needed
  RUN npm install http-server

  # Install dev deps too
  RUN npm install --omit=production

  ARG WORKDIR=/usr/chromeservice
  WORKDIR $WORKDIR

  COPY --from=builder --chown=pptruser:pptruser $WORKDIR/dist/test ./dist/test

  RUN mkdir /home/pptruser/www
  VOLUME /home/pptruser/www

  # This is the port, where my http test server is running
  EXPOSE 20002 
 
  RUN printf '#!/bin/bash \n\
    set -e\n\
    npx http-server /home/pptruser/www -a 0.0.0.0 -p 20002 > /dev/null 2>&1  &  \n\
    node node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --forbid-pending --forbid-only --timeout 30000 --fail-zero --color --recursive "dist/test/**/*.spec.js" \n\
  ' > /home/pptruser/run_all_tests.sh

  RUN chmod +x /home/pptruser/run_all_tests.sh

 
  CMD ["/home/pptruser/run_all_tests.sh"]

  # Use this, to be able to ssh into the container wihout running the tests, but the fileserver won't be running, too
  #CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I haven't finished my build script for this, currently I only run the tester stage, tag it, execute it and check for error code.
When tests are green I am going to create a build-script

build script:

```
# My Dockerfile is in a subdirectory, that's why I am `cd ..` from `$PSScriptRoot`
docker buildx build  --file=.\MydockerFileFromAbove.dockerfile "$PSScriptRoot\.."  -t chrome-service

# Executing (currently only the test stage)
# The volume is ONLY needed for the http test server 
docker run -p9987:9987 -p20002:20002 -v "<Path to test-http-server data>/www/:/home/pptruser/www:ro" --rm chrome-service

# Read $LASTEXITCODE, if it is ok, buildx the production stage by passsing
# --target=production to buildx
```

The build script is WIP, therefore I am taging the test image actually as chrome-service, which is stupid and will be fixed later